# Using cast in insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am inserting some raw data into a table in MS SQL 2005 from excel.
Some of these data are not formatted correctly ie the amount colum is formatteT as a number 12345 whereas i need to be like 123.45 so i use this 
`CAST(TRANSACTION_HISTORY.AMOUNT  AS decimal) / 100` 
to convert it correctly.
However is there a way to use the cast in an insert statement??

thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can use **CAST** in any kind of statement(Insert, update, delete, select) where you use data.

```
Insert into table1 values( CAST(col1 as nvarchar(50)) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using a linked server or openquery to get the data from excel. You can cast in the select statement.

So

```
INSERT INTO YourTable
SELECT Cast(Transaction_History.Amount AS Decimal)/100
FROM EXCELLINK...[$Sheet1]
```

You could also just update all values in the table after you do the import

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = YourColumn/100
```