# Casting an inserted string to a date in the same insert

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2017 - although this post is quite old, I still referred to it: [Using cast in insert statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003164/using-cast-in-insert-statement) (the answer with 6 votes), but I'm getting an error when trying to perform this simple `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table (Name, DateOfBirth, DateOfBirth_Normalized)
VALUES ('John Doe', '1943-09-08', CAST(DateOfBirth AS DateTime))
```

The error I'm getting is that the `DateOfBirth` inside the `CAST` statement is an invalid column name.

How can I achieve this?

FYI, `DateOfBirth` is `nvarchar(50)` and `DateOfBirth_Normalized` is `DateTime`.

**EDIT 1**: this is for a stored procedure, so the `DateOfBirth` value will be different for every `INSERT` and therefore can not simply be passed as the string value, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: What is `DateOfBirth`? What is should be is a litteral date, or a variable name, which it doesn't appear to be.

Comment: CAST('1943-09-08' AS DateTime)

Comment: @MortimerCat the code is for a Stored Procedure so the actual string is not known.

Comment: @GMB it's a string coming in from user input. We then need to populate the normalized field with the date-format version of it.

Comment: You would be passing a parameter to the stored procedure.  I would expect to see your SQL end something like VALUES(@name,@dob,CAST(@dob AS DateTime))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544752/create-a-stored-procedure-to-insert-a-new-data-in-a-table   The answers give a simple and similar stored procedure

Comment: Thanks @MortimerCat - parameterizing everything made it work.